# referencing a column in a function

Tags: r

I am hoping someone can help with the following, as I think it is quite simple but I am struggling with it.

I have two dataframes (simplified below):

```
dataframe 1
Area 1    Area 2    Area 3    Area 4    
 Yes        No         No        No
 Yes        No         No        Yes
 No         Yes        Yes       No etc

dataframe 2
rep 1    rep 2     rep 3    etc
 0.1      0.2        0.3
 0.2      0.1        0.4
 0.5      0.6        0.8
```

There can be around 100,000 rows in each of these dataframes.

I would like the sum of each column in dataframe 2 by the rows that equal "Yes" in dataframe 1.  Ideally I would like to end up with

```
     Area 1    Area  2    Area 3    Area 4
rep1   0.3       0.5        0.5      0.2
rep2   0.3       0.6        0.6      0.1
rep3   0.7       0.8        0.8      0.4
```

etc

I have the following code that gives me the correct dataframe output but colSums is zero, as I am unsure of how to reference the column correctly to subset the rows by:

```
extractedsums<-apply(dataframe1, 2,  function(i){
df<-dataframe1$i=="Yes"
i<-colSums(data.frame(dataframe2=dataframe2[df,]))
})
```

The problem is in the line

```
 df<-dataframe1$i=="Yes"
```

as it isn't referencing the dataframe1 column correctly.

I have tried searching for the correct way to reference the column correctly but I haven't been able to understand the literature enough to work out a solution.

If anyone can point me in the right direction on how to correct this or of a more efficient way to complete the above I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

I am not sure how to use dput  but the following should generate example code

```
Area1<-c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No")
Area2<-c("No","Yes", "Yes", "No") 
Area3<-c("No", "No","Yes", "Yes")
Area4<-c("No","Yes","No","Yes")
dataframe1<-data.frame(cbind(Area1, Area2, Area3, Area4))

rep1<-c(1:3)
rep2<-c(4:6)
rep3<-c(2:4)
dataframe2<-data.frame(cbind(rep1, rep2, rep3))
```

Comment: If you turned dataframe1 into a matrix with 1s and 0s, you could use matrix multiplication.

Comment: It would be helpful if you dput() some sample data. Since you have spaces in the column headers, I can't read.table("clipboard") the data. Also, in your desired result, the row names don't have spaces.

Comment: @Henry I understand how to turn the dataframe in to a matrix with 1's and 0's but surely I will end up with the same problem with referencing the column, as I will need the sum of (dataframe 2 *dataframe 1 $column1) etc.

Comment: @user1071558 Sorry I don't understand your goal. With the sample data provided (Area1 .. Area4 ), how would the desired result look like? I thought both dataframes must have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an illustration of my comment that matrix multiplication would do this:

```
> areas <- matrix(c(1,1,0, 0,0,1, 0,0,1, 0,1,0), nrow=3)
> reps <- matrix(c(0.1,0.2,0.5, 0.2,0.1,0.6, 0.3,0.4,0.8), nrow=3)
>
> t(reps) %*% areas
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.3  0.5  0.5  0.2
[2,]  0.3  0.6  0.6  0.1
[3,]  0.7  0.8  0.8  0.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, this gave me the answer that I needed.